# In Hyperledger Fabric is it possible to connect 2 Org's on 2 different machines

Tags: linux, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

In Hyperledger Fabric is it possible to connect 2 Org's on 2 different machines(i.e. org1 on PC1 and org2 on PC2). If possible can you please suggest some steps?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is yes, though Docker Composer, which is how most of the samples are managed, won't do this without some heavy lifting.

You should take a look at [Hyperledger Cello](https://github.com/hyperledger/cello) project as a means of deploying to multiple hosts leveraging kubernetes. It can deploy to most clouds supporting a kubernetes cluster capability, or can be used locally.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible. Setting ip address instead of localhost for containers. Utilizing k8s or docker-swarm to handle cross-host containers.

Comment: Is their some working example for it or something to refer?